# Decrypt PHP AES/CBC encrypted string in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, aes, mcrypt, rijndael

I'm getting literally crazy trying to decrypt in JavaScript a string encrypted in PHP with the following code snippet:

```
function myencrypt($str) {
    $iv = '1234567890abcdef';
    $key = 'abcdef1234567890';

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return bin2hex($encrypted);
}
```

I've tried slowAES, gibberish-aes and some other available JS libraries, but always failed to correctly decrypt a single string.

I've also extensively searched in SO, but was unable to find a solution applicable to my situation.

Any pointer toward the right solution would be more than welcome!

Thanks,
Alessandro

Comment: Make sure both your IV, key and ciphertext are using the same encoding on both sides, and that you are using the same mode of operation (i.e. CBC in your case) in both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the [crypto-js library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)? Sorry but i'm not sure what `mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128'` does exactly but if it just uses CBC it should work

Comment: Thank you Manuel, will check it out and let you know.